# Use "event's" output as a variable

Tags: javascript, variables, object, extjs, extjs4

I have a problem to manipulate checkbox values. The ‘change’ event on checkboxes returns an object, in my case:

```
{"val1":"member","val2":"book","val3":"journal","val4":"new_member","val5":"cds"}
```

The above object needed to be transformed in order the search engine to consume it like:

```
{ member,book,journal,new_member,cds}
```

I have done that with the below code block:

```
var formcheckbox = this.getFormcheckbox();
formcheckbox.on('change', function(checkbox, value){

                var arr=[];

                for (var i in value) {
                    arr.push(value[i])
                };

                var wrd = new Array(arr);
                    var joinwrd = wrd.join(",");
                        var filter = '{' + joinwrd + '}';

                        //console.log(filter);

                //Ext.Msg.alert('Output', '{' + joinwrd + '}');

                });
```

The problem is that I want to the “change” event’s output (“var filter” that is producing the: { member,book,journal,new_member,cds})  to use it elsewhere. I tried to make the whole event a variable (var output = “the change event”) but it doesn’t work.

Maybe it is a silly question but I am a newbie and I need a little help.

Thank you in advance,

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make `filter` a global variable and use it where ever you need it.

```
// global variable for the search filter
var filter = null;

var formcheckbox = this.getFormcheckbox();
formcheckbox.on('change', function(checkbox, value){
    var arr = [],
    i,
    max;

    // the order of the keys isn't guaranteed to be the same in a for(... in ...) loop
    // if the order matters (as it looks like) better get them one by one by there names
    for (i = 0, max = 5; i <= max; i++) {
        arr.push(value["val" + i]);
    }

    // save the value in a global variable
    filter = "{" + arr.join(",") + "}";

    console.log(filter);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. But i didn't make it. I need some help. I used the below code block. How do i save a value in global variable? Thanks again <pre><code>var filter = null;
      
      var formcheckbox = this.getFormcheckbox();
      formcheckbox.on('change', function(checkbox, value){
       var arr = [],
       i,
       max;
      
      
       for (i = 0, max = 5; i <= max; i++) {
        arr.push(value["val" + i]);
       }
      
       
       filter = "{" + arr.join(",") + "}";
      
       return filter;
       
      });
      
      console.log(filter);</code></pre>

Comment: You do it as with any other variable (global or not). `var x = ...` In this case `filter` will be null unless your `change`-handler gets called.

Comment: The change handler is fired when i check any (one or more) check-boxes. But when i console.log(filter) it is outputing "null". What i am missing? Please help. Thanks

Comment: Did you click a checkbox before `console.log(filter)`? Is your  event handler executed when you click a checkbox? Have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XYVyQ/), maybe it helps understanding/testing.

Comment: I have to admit that you are a gentleman. You are patient with newbies. Many many thanks. Be well.
Tom

Answer (score 2):

Just pass `filter` to the function that will use it. You'd have to call it from inside the `change` handler anyway if you wanted something to happen:

```
formcheckbox.on('change', function(cb, value){
    //...
    var filter = "{" + arr.join(",") + "}";
    useFilter(filter);
});


function useFilter(filter){
    // use the `filter` var here
}
```

Comment: Much thanks for your attention. I tried this:<pre>formcheckbox.on('change', function(checkbox, value){
    
    var arr=[];
   
    for (var i in value) {
     arr.push(value[i])
    };
    
    var wrd = new Array(arr);
     var joinwrd = wrd.join(",");
      var filter = '{' + joinwrd + '}';
      
      //console.log(filter);
      useFilter(filter);
       
    //Ext.Msg.alert('Output', '{' + joinwrd + '}');
    
    });

     var a = function useFilter(filter){
      //console.log(filter);
      return filter;
     };
     
   console.log(a);</pre>But it is giving me an error. Help